# Unable to identify nzec error in code

Tags: java, exception, runtime

I was challenged with the following question from a coding site :

==================================================================================
Given K prime numbers and T queries of form Ai, Bi, for each query print the number of integers between Ai and Bi (both inclusive) that are divisible by atleast one of the K given primes.

Input
First line: K and T.
Second line: K primes.
Next T lines, each contain Ai, Bi.

Output
Print T lines, denoting the answer to each of the T queries.

Constraints
1 ≤ K ≤ 10
1 ≤ T ≤ 100
1 ≤ A ≤ B ≤ 109
Each prime ≤ 107
Sample Input (Plaintext Link)
2 1
2 3
1 10
Sample Output (Plaintext Link)
7
Explanation
2,3,4,6,8,9,10 are the 7 numbers.

=======================================================================

When I run the following code (in system compiler) it works well, but when I submitted it to the site, all test cases throw nzec runtime error. Unfortunately the site does not share test cases but they can be created using the question.

Can any one please explain why there is a nzec error? I have used java so code is throwing an exception that needs to be caught:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

class TestClass {
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] line1 = scan.nextLine().split(" ");

    int fPrime,first,last,count=0,cur;boolean duplicate=false;

    int K = Integer.parseInt(line1[0]);

    int T = Integer.parseInt(line1[1]);
    int[][] num=new int[2][T];
   // int arr[];

    String[] line2 = scan.nextLine().split(" ");     

    if(T<=100 )
    {
      for(int k=0;k<T;k++)
    {
        if(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
         String[] line3 = scan.nextLine().split(" ");   
        num[0][k] = Integer.parseInt(line3[0]);
        num[1][k] = Integer.parseInt(line3[1]);
    //  System.out.print("num0 = " + num[0][k]);
    //  System.out.println("num1 = " + num[1][k]);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Lines of Ai and Bi are missing. Make sure T lines exist");
        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("Error! T>100");
    }

  if(T<=100)
  {
 for(int l = 0; l < T; l++)
  {                              
      first = num[0][l];
      last =  num[1][l];
      int arr[] = new int[last]; 
      cur=0;
    //   System.out.println("first = " +first);
      //  System.out.println("last = " +last);
    for(int i = first; i<=last; i++ )
    {

         for(int j = 0; j < K; j++)
    {
         fPrime = Integer.parseInt(line2[j]);
    //   System.out.println("fPrime = " +fPrime);
   if(( fPrime<=1000000) && (first<=1000000000 && last<=1000000000)){
        if(i%fPrime==0)
        {
            // System.out.println("Gotcha num " + i);
            for(int a = 0; a < arr.length; a++)
            {               
                     if (arr[a] == i)
                     {
                             duplicate=true;
                         //    System.out.print("arr"+a+" = " + i);
                     }                         
            }                                                       

                     if(duplicate==true)
                             {
                                        duplicate=false;      
                            }
                       else
                             {
                                 arr[cur++]=i;              
                                 count++;  
                              }
          }
    }
          else
          {
             System.out.println("Make Sure 1 ? A ? B ? 10^9 Each prime ? 10^7" );
          }
         }     

  }           
   System.out.println(count);
    }    
}
else System.out.println("T can not be greater than 100");
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please put a bit more effort into making your code readable - the indentation is all over the place, particularly for the second part of your code. The more readable your code is, the more likely you are to get help. Use spaces rather than tabs for indentation in Stack Overflow. (It looks like you're currently using a mixture, which is never a great position to be in.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips Jon, I will surely keep this in mind for my future questions!